# Pentaho 7.1 Job No Longer Runs after I run it a second time

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pentaho-cde

I'm running into a weird issue with Pentaho 7.1. I run a job that I created and it runs perfectly and quickly the first time I run it.

The job is an ETL Job consisting of a Start widget, 7 Transformations running in a sequence, and a Success widget.

I'm confused as to why the job runs once, and when I try to run it again it says "Spoon - Starting job..." and then the job just hangs.

If I delete the job and I create a brand new one, I am then able to run the job once and I am stuck again with the job no longer able to run after that. I don't understand why the job keeps hanging after it gets executed once, and it is then 100% broken after a Successful run...

I turned up the logging in Pentaho 7.1 Spoon, and it shows this continuously...

> 2018/08/14 17:30:24 - Job1 - Triggering heartbeat signal for
>   ported_jobs at every 10 seconds  2018/08/14 17:30:34 - Job1 -
>   Triggering heartbeat signal for ported_jobs at every 10 seconds 
>   2018/08/14 17:30:44 - Job1 - Triggering heartbeat signal for
>   ported_jobs at every 10 seconds  2018/08/14 17:30:54 - Job1 -
>   Triggering heartbeat signal for ported_jobs at every 10 seconds

I can't seem to put my finger on why this happening.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Probable answer: Check that your transformations are not opening the same database for input and output. A quick check may to run the first transformation directly (without the job) and see if it locks.

Comment: So I run the job using kitchen.sh -file"pathto_the_file" and the job.kjb works perfectly every time... I don't get why the GUI is not letting me run it. I also run queries against the DB when the hung jobs are running, and I am able to query the DB just fine, so I know that the DB isn't hung or locked

Comment: Strange the GUI and kitchen is line for line the same java code. Do you have he same problem with a transformation (without job) ?

Answer (score 0):

Happened because the server db you want to update are slow to respond. Probably high CPU and RAM. I tried to increase the RAM and CPU for the db server, now my job runs okay.